# The value sent with jquery or Ajax with following code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send a value with this code. How can I do that? First sent the value in this page http://localhost/abc/pagi/. then I am getting value and run SQL and then need this code. I am trying, but my code is not working. Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#results" ).load( "http://localhost/demo/pagi/"); //load initial records

    //executes code below when user click on pagination links
    jQuery("#results").on( "click", ".paginationss a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
        var page = jQuery(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
        jQuery("#results").load("http://localhost/demo/pagi/",{"page":page}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
            jQuery(".loading-div").hide(); //once done, hide loading element
        });

    });

    function searchFilter(page_num) {
        page_num = page_num?page_num:0;
        var keywords    = jQuery('#curent_user_mail').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/demo/pagi/',
            data:'page='+page_num+'&keywords='+keywords

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: what do you mean by *code is not working*? have you checked your console for any errors?

Comment: pass a object in your data

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve]

Comment: data:{ 'page':page_num, 'keywords':keywords}